# Drawing a series of UIImages and memory issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, out-of-memory

I need to draw a series of large UIImages on top of each other and I am coming up against memory issues and I was wondering if anybody has a solution.

The code below gives you an example of how my function calls work. The functions have been simplified to show my main issue.

The function "generateImage" has a for loop that calls into a subclass that also returns images that have been generated from a series of paths. I have put @autoreleasepools around the calls so that the images that are generated are immediately deallocated after they are used, but this does not seem to be working and when arrayOfSubImages grows I come up against memory issues.

```
-( UIImage *)   generateImage
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( CGSizeMake( 1000, 1000 ), NO, 0.0 );

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

        for ( SubImage *subImage in arrayOfSubImages ) {
            UIImage     *aImage = [ subImage imageFromPaths ];
            [ aImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero ];
        }

        UIGraphicsPopContext();

        UIImage     *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image;
    }
}
```

The SubImage that is called from generateImage

```
-( UIImage *)   imageFromPaths
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( CGSizeMake( 1000, 1000 ), NO, 0.0 );

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        UIGraphicsPushContext(context);


        for ( UIBezierPath *path in arrayOfPaths ) {
            [ path fill ];
        }


        UIGraphicsPopContext();

        UIImage     *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Reza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had similar problems in the past.  Try adding an @autoreleasepool *within* your for-loops because you're likely running into memory problems by performing several memory intensive operations within a tight loop. Memory won't automatically release itself until a loop is over even if that loop is contained in an autoreleasepool -- you need to release each individual iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the images to nil directly after using them should release the memory, like so:

```
-( UIImage *)   generateImage
{
    @autoreleasepool {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( CGSizeMake( 1000, 1000 ), NO, 0.0 );

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

    for ( SubImage *subImage in arrayOfSubImages ) {
        UIImage     *aImage = [ subImage imageFromPaths ];
        [ aImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero ];
        aImage = nil;
    }

    UIGraphicsPopContext();

    UIImage     *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead using temp variables,
Like:

```
UIimage * image=
```

You can define an instance temp variables in you .h file,
Like:

```
UIImage * _image;
```

Then use it everywhere you define a new image, which needs to be deallocated.
It can guarantee you reset memory in time.

Scott is right. I forgot this issue. Release within Loop is the key

Comment: This did not work and I didn't expect it to, as each time through the loop the _image variable is set to another variable and hence the old variable will get added to the release pool which then grows.