# Adding border to UIImages memory issue

Tags: swift, uikit, uigraphicscontext

I'm trying to add a border to my images by drawing it in a context but the memory keeps growing.

```
func borderImages(image: [UIImage]) -> [UIImage] {
    let width: CGFloat = 3000
    let height: CGFloat = 3000
    var borderedImages = [UIImage]()

    for image in images {
        autoreleasepool {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: width, height: height), true, 1.0)

            let x: CGFloat = (width - image.size.width)/2.0
            let y: CGFloat = (height - image.size.height)/2.0

            let rect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
            image.draw(in: rect)

            if let borderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
                borderedImages.append(borderedImage)

            }
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }
    }

    return borderedImages
}
```

I tried adding autoreleasepool as suggested from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20304615/drawing-a-series-of-uiimages-and-memory-issues). Doesn't seem to make any difference. This is what allocations look like before it crashes.[image] Any suggestions on how I can fix this? Am I using autoreleasepool wrong?

Comment: How is this function used?  Do you call it just once or is it a case that you keep calling it and are generating more and more bordered images without removing the original ones.  That would explain the memory increase.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth It’s called once. I pass in an array of images that are used to generate bordered images

Comment: How many images?  You are going to end up with two copies of everything (original and bordered).  That could build up really quickly.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth 100 images. Shouldn't the bordered image get deallocated after each iteration?

Comment: The local ones in the function will I just meant you will pass in an array of images and return an array of images thus have two copies of everything afterwards (which I guess is the plan).  Roughly how big are the images?  When you say 'keeps growing' does it every stop or grows until crashing?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth you can see on that image that the memory goes up to 2.3 GiB(crashes) when I'm trying to process 100 images. When I do 50 images, it goes up to 1.5 GiB(doesn't crash) and then it clears all at once, back to my normal 10 mb memory usage. Is there a way to clear the memory as I border the image and not all at once after the for loop is done?

Comment: How big are the original 100 images as it's real easy to have that many images used up all available memory in your returned array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162169/discussion-between-user2995344-and-upholderoftruth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after discussing it and checking out the images it looks like trying to process 100 at once it just too much for the memory handling of an iOS device.

The solution is going to be to batch the files for processing something like this:

1. Create next batch.
2. Process/upload images in the current batch.
3. Dispose of the current batch.
4. Repeat from 1 above.

Doing that you should never have to hold too many in memory at once.